# strftime not giving correct output with %C option - Solaris 10

Tags: c, solaris, strftime

We are using /usr/xpg4/bin as default path in our profile.
We are printing the output of variable "curr_date" here:

```
   lt = time(NULL);
   ltime=localtime(localtime(&lt));
   strftime(curr_date,sizeof(curr_date),"%m/%d/%y%C",ltime);
```

We get the output as "06/27/13Thu Jun 27 02:39:34 PDT" instead of "06/27/1320".

Do you know what should be the format specifiers that should work here?

Thanks

Comment: Typed `man strftime` on the command line?

Comment: man says:
 Standard conforming
     %C       Century number (the year divided by 100  and  trun-
              cated to an integer as a decimal number [01,99]).

              This is standard-conforming behavior for  standards
              first supported by Solaris 2.4 through Solaris 10.

Comment: But instead of getting "20" for %C, we are getting "Thu Jun 27 02:39:34 PDT"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of `/usr/xpg4/bin` in your $PATH only selects the standard compliant commands, it does not change function calls in your programs to use the standards compliant versions.

As described in the [Solaris standards(5) man page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29043/standards-5.html#scrolltoc) there are various #defines and compiler flags you need to use to specify compliance for various standards.

For instance, taking your code snippet and expanding it to this standalone test program:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    time_t lt;
    struct tm *ltime;
    char curr_date[80];

    lt = time(NULL);
    ltime = localtime(&lt);
    strftime(curr_date, sizeof(curr_date), "%m/%d/%y%C", ltime); 
    printf("%s\n", curr_date);
    return 0;
}
```

Then compiling with the different flags shows the different behavior:

```
% cc -o /tmp/strftime /tmp/strftime.c
% /tmp/strftime
06/30/13Sun Jun 30 20:28:00 PDT 2013

% cc -xc99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -o /tmp/strftime /tmp/strftime.c
% /tmp/strftime
06/30/1320
```

The default mode is backwards compatible with the traditional Solaris code, the second form requests compliance with the C99 and XPG6 (Unix03) standards.

Answer (score 0):

Have a good look at the code between call to `strftime()` and printing `curr_date`.  You're overwriting `curr_data` somewhere, because the start of what you print is correct.  Might also be something fishy with memory management of `curr_data`; how is it defined, did you allocate memory for `curr_data`?

Set a breakpoint right after `strftime()` and you'll see it holds the expected/correct string.

Comment: Hi..We are seeing that the same code is working on other operating systems like HP-UX but fails on Solaris. Our guess is might be internally its using something similar in functionality to /usr/bin/date instead of /usr/xpg4/bin. But not sure if there is alternative provided for this situation.  


> /usr/bin/date +%C  
Fri Jun 28 13:31:23 PDT 2013  

> /usr/xpg4/bin/date +%C  
20